# $X, Y$ subspaces of $V$, $\dim(X) \geq \dim(Y) \implies \exists f$ linear s.t. $f(X)=Y$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, dimension-theory-algebra

Suppose that $V$ is a $K$-vector space and $X, Y$ vector subspaces of $V$ with $\dim(X) \geq \dim(Y) \implies \exists$ a linear map $f : V \to V$ such that $f(X)=Y$.

I do not know what strategy to adapt to resolve this exercise.

I thought of restricting $f$ to $X \to V$ and showing that $\dim(\mathrm{Im} \; f)=\dim Y$, but it does not lead me anywhere.

I thought of treating first the case  $\dim(X) = \dim(Y)=n$, if $Y \subset X$ we can say that $X=Y \implies f = \rm Id$, if not let $B_X = \{x_i \lvert i \in [0,n]\}$ a basis of $X$ and $B_Y = \{y_i \lvert i \in [0,n]\}$ a basis of $Y$. Let $f : X \to Y$ a map defined by the following $f(\sum\alpha_ix_i)=\alpha_iy_i$. We can verify that it is linear : let $a,b \in X$ with $a=\sum a_i x_i$ and $b=\sum b_i x_i$, $\lambda \in K$. $f(\lambda a + b)=\sum (\lambda a_i + b_i)y_i = \lambda \sum a_i f_i + \sum b_i f_i = \lambda f(a) + f(b)$. This map is obviously surjective.

For the case $\dim(X) > \dim(Y)$ I guess I can do the same with $B_X = \{x_i \lvert i \in [0,n]\}$ a basis of $X$ and $B_Y = \{y_i \lvert i \in [0,n-k]\}$ a basis of $Y$ and just send the $n-k$ first $x_i$ on $y_i$ and the additional $x_i$ on $0_V$ ? Honestly not sure about this (but I think of X as a plane in $\mathbb R^3$ and $Y$ a straight line then $\dim(X)=2<1=\dim(Y)$ and by sending a vector of $X$'s basis to any nonzero vector of $Y$ and the other vector of the $X$ basis to $0_V$ it seems to work but I need to check the linearity of $f$ in this case)

I think there is some more clever ways to do this, maybe by finding a single map $f : X \to Y$ that is surjective.

Comment: Why do you doubt your construction $x_i \mapsto \begin{cases} y_i, & i \le \dim(Y) \\ 0, & i > \dim(Y)? \end{cases}$  Depending on your definitions, it is not even possible to discuss dimension without using bases, so you already have bases lying around.

Comment: So is my answer right ? Or do I need to change something ?

Comment: I think it is less useful just to get a [right/wrong](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3980555/x-y-subspaces-of-v-dimx-geq-dimy-implies-exists-f-linear-s-t#comment8212956_3980555) diagnosis than first to figure out why you doubt that your construction is correct.

Comment: Maybe I would be careful about the intersection $X\cap Y$.
If $X\cap Y = \{0\}$, so you can take some basis $B_X$ for $X$, $B_Y$ for $Y$ and $B$ for $V$, such that $B_X\subset B$ and $B_Y\subset B$. 
If $X\cap Y\neq \{0\}$, you could take a basis for $X\cap Y$, a basis for $X-Y$ and a basis for $Y-X$, and then work out with your $f$.
The definition of your $f$ could be "send the basis vectors of $X$ to the basis of $Y$  until you kill all the vectors of the basis of $Y$, then send all that's left to $0$"

Comment: Oh, I missed the fact that we have $f : V \to V$, not just $f : X \to V$.  @MateusRocha is [right](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3980555/x-y-subspaces-of-v-dimx-geq-dimy-implies-exists-f-linear-s-t#comment8213014_3980555) that you will need to extend your basis of $X$ to one of $V$, but I don't think the intersection $X \cap Y$ particularly matters, since no nice behaviour of $f$ on $X \cap Y$ is prescribed.  (Also, I would notice that there is in general no meaning, or at least no *single* meaning, of $X - Y$ and $Y - X$ as vector spaces.)

Comment: @LSpice of course it is less useful. My doubt was based on the way I found the construction : I needed to write something to show that I tried to work on the problem and not just asking for an answer so the construction for I gave was just the first idea that came to my mind and that seemed to work at first sight so there were high chances that my proof could be wrong.

Comment: Once you extend your basis of $X$ to one of $V$, your construction is fine.  I do not see any need to worry about $X \cap Y$.  (I think perhaps @MateusRocha may have seen your comment that, if $X = Y$ and $f(X) = Y$, then $f$ is the identity—which is not true—and thought that you meant to require that $f$ was the identity on $X \cap Y$.  You *don't* require that, right?)